# How to get a proper value from the FQL Message table's Attachment Field?

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk

The following is what I get anytime I make a call to Message.attachment:

```
"media":[],
"name":"",
"caption":"",
"description":"",
"properties":[],
"icon":"https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
"fb_object_type":"","fb_object_id":"",
"tagged_ids":[]
```

This value is beyond useless to me; The targeted inbox messages have links, uploaded pictures, links to pictures, but they all return this...  I expected something more useful, like a `url` to an attached image.

Am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate of:

[View attachments in threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192430/view-attachments-in-threads)

I'd subscribe and repro this bug as well:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/105357702931610

Comment: haha.  mine is even less useful than theirs....I'm really curious if its the same problem.  Am I supposed to make your 'this is a duplicate' answer as correct if no one else has an answer?