# How to retrieve message attachment with FQL?

Tags: facebook, message, facebook-fql, messaging

I know that according to http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/311146672312127 it is impossible to retrieve attachments using Open Graph API. What about FQL?

```
SELECT attachment FROM message
WHERE thread_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx AND viewer_id=xxxxxxxxxx LIMIT 925,1
```

Gives me:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "attachment": {
        "media": [
        ], 
        "name": "", 
        "caption": "", 
        "description": "", 
        "properties": [
        ], 
        "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif", 
        "fb_object_type": "", 
        "fb_object_id": "", 
        "tagged_ids": [
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be unsupported yet. You can use this:

[View attachments in threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192430/view-attachments-in-threads)

It will be supperted in unified_message, I guess.