# Can't get image-attachments from facebook conversations using FQL or Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm making an application, where I need to access peoples inbox and attachments (stickers and images) in it.

From Googling around this seems rather hard, not possible with the graph api, and not very documented, although I do have permission to "read_inbox".

What I've found out, is that I can use FQL to query for attachments for a specifc message. Here's my query:

```
SELECT attachment FROM message WHERE message_id = "730111050341010_3" ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET
```

This gives me no errors, and it returns a valid "attachment->media"-array when the attachment is a sticker. Just look at this result:

```
[{"attachment":{"media":[{"href":"https:\/\/fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-prn1\/t39.1997\/851577_246547505491999_862435009_n.png","alt":"","type":"link","src":"https:\/\/fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-prn1\/t39.1997\/851577_246547505491999_862435009_n.png"}],"name":"","href":"https:\/\/fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-prn1\/t39.1997\/851577_246547505491999_862435009_n.png","caption":"","description":"","properties":[],"icon":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yD\/r\/aS8ecmYRys0.gif","tagged_ids":[],"sticker_id":"227878347358915"}}]
```

but whenever it's a picture uploaded by a user, it returns this: (no trace of the picture [no media-array, nor href-field])

```
[{"attachment":{"media":[],"name":"","caption":"","description":"","properties":[],"fb_object_type":"","fb_object_id":"","icon":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yD\/r\/aS8ecmYRys0.gif","tagged_ids":[]}}]
```

Is there any way I can get a users uploaded attachment from facebook?

Btw. [View attachments in threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192430/view-attachments-in-threads) doesn't seem to return any "attachments"-array for me