# How to get PDF/TXT/xls file attachment link from Facebook Direct Message using Facebook Graph API v2.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm retrieving Facebook Posts/Direct Messages/Comments using facebook Graph API v2.0.

I'm able to get image attachment details with its LINK on Post Attachments / Comment Attachments  / Direct Message attachments.

But I'm not able to get attachment link in Direct Message if the attachment is a text file or a xls file or a simple pdf file.

Following is the attachment array sent from FACEBOOK for a text file which includes only mime-types and name of the file but no link.

```
[attachments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [data] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 1560065847610348
                                                            [mime_type] => text/plain
                                                            [name] => linux.txt
                                                            [size] => 1783
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )
```

Is there any other means through which it can be fetched, I've searched a lot but didnt find any solutions to it. Is there any documentation available for it or a tweak through which it can be fetched.

Comment: [There was a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192430/view-attachments-in-threads) but the endpoint seems to not work anymore...

+1 because I'm stuck in the same situation, I didn't found a way to get the attachment content via Graph API