# Facebook Graph getattachment method returning "unknown method" error

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to write an application which can archive your Facebook messages and their attachments, something similar to the amazing tool https://github.com/bnvk/social-archiver, but i have a problem with non-image attachments, say a audio file for example.

According to this [View attachments in threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192430/view-attachments-in-threads), the solution is the messaging.getattachment api call, with the proper parameters, now it looks like this is working for some people, but when i do it, through a browser direct call as well as with the python code mentioned before the response is always the same:

```
{"error_code":3,"error_msg":"Unknown method","request_args"
```

followed by all my parameters.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something wrong with this api endpoint at this moment? Am I passing the parameters the wrong way? Maybe someone who got this working can put an example of how they passed their parameters(not the access token of course :() but maybe im putting the mid parameter the wrong way.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `messaging.getattachment` method is no longer available and only in use with Facebook Native mobile applications. You will need an access_token from one of the applications for example, Facebook Messenger for iPhone to use it.

Comment: how can you get an access token from Facebook Messenger, for example?

Comment: Officially you cannot. Unofficially there are ways, e.g. HTTP listen for the token, you will have to search the internet for them.